# Allow user to directly download a file clicking on a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

In my server which I shared, to store some files and I can access it from the run command like this from my local PC:

`\\myserver\myfolder\file.pdf` (which is technically on `C:\myfolder\file.pdf` in the server itself)

I am trying to display a link on my ASP.net webpage, built using C#, so the user can click on it and download the file to their local PC. My partial code-behind is this:

```
string newFileServer = "//" + System.Environment.MachineName + @"/myfolder/file.pdf";
tc.Text = "A completed PDF for " + k + " was generated successfully and saved to <a href=" + newFileServer + ">" + newFileServer + "</a>";
```

When I hover over the link in my local PC, I see the following:

```
http://myserver/myfolder/file.pdf
```

When I click on it, I get a `404 File or directory not found` error.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: You want a link in a web page to use a UNC path to open a file, is that correct?

Comment: Yes... Show the OPEN/SAVE dialog from the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the folder in IIS as a virtual directory and then set your path accordingly.

1. Go to IIS manager
2. Select the site you want to have the files be accessible in.
3. Right click and select add virtual directory.
4. Give the path an alias.
5. Then set the physical path.
6. On the page create a link from http:// [domain] / [virtual directory] / [File]
   or use the virtual path / [Virtual Directory] / [File]

********** EDIT ***********

tc.Text = "A completed PDF for " + k + " was generated successfully and saved to 
    `<a href='/PDFGenerate/file.pdf'>file.pdf</a>`";

Comment: Thank you, that might work actually. I created a virtual directory `PDFGenerate` in IIS, How would I replace my code from my question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried server.MapPath("path to file")

Comment: It gives me the `C:\` drive.

Answer (score 1):

your link is wrong patch, http or (localhost)?

**you have not permission to access to out of server patch**

Comment: I created a virtual folder in my site pointing to the physical folder in the server as @CBRRacer mentioned. How to figure out how to fix the link... That will work I am guessing?